# Elasticsearch complex regexp matches

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, logging

I am using elasticsearch logger and need to find an endpoint with this structure

> api/v1/sites/:id/meta

I have checked [elasticsearch docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html), but couldn't find any example for complicated cases.
so far the best result I could get is

```
{
  "query": {
    "regexp": {
      "request": {
        "value": "api/v1"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but since I have other apis with meta word I need more precise search. When I change it like
`api/v1/sites/.*/meta`
or
`(sites.*meta)`
I don't get any results but should get them.Any of regex I used in Elastic search logger where valid regex in [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/aW7zC3/1) site, but non of them worked in elastic search. Is there special syntax?

Comment: What is the field type of request field?

Comment: It is a string.

Comment: it seems like it has a problem with sign "/"

Comment: Please have a look here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pathhierarchy-tokenizer.html and here https://spinscale.de/posts/2021-03-17-search-hierarchies-using-elasticsearch-path-hierarchy-tokenizer.html

Comment: @ArmenSanoyan, when they asked you about the type. They ask you about the mapping you use for the field containing the URL. You get get the mapping of the index via `GET <index_name>/_mapping`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Musab Dogan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10685211/musab-dogan), [Lupanoide](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5362842/lupanoide) and [Paulo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4534923/paulo) I fixed the query. I changed `request` to `request.keyword` and regex started to work. Here is the reason.
So there are two similar types for text in Elasticsearch. One is text and the other is keyword. The difference between them is is that [text is analysed](https://codecurated.com/blog/basics-of-elasticsearch-for-developer/) before saving (sliced into chunks). The keyword is saved without any changes, which lets you do regex search.